# how to display point index next to the point?

Tags: geometry-nodes

for debug purposes,
I'm trying to display indices as a text field next to my points.
But I don't understand how to catch every point index value.

[image]

Could someone help ?

[image]

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building on Chris' answer, here's a way to display numbers larger than 9! I built a node group called "Label points", which takes a Geometry, an field based on the points, and a font size. It works by creating the "tens digit" separately, and shifting them to the correct position:

[image]

It can be used like this:

[image]

Resulting in an output like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is NOT a complete solution, but a path to the solution ;)

with this node tree, you can show the indices from 0-9

[image]

[image]

to make it work for more numbers > 9 you have to combine the right numbers. So that's more math than really geometry nodes.

[image]

for really good help you could study his work here:

https://artofriaz3d.gumroad.com/l/indexviewerfields

Comment: Thanks for the tip with the index viewer! ;-)

Comment: you are welcome! Meanwhile a build even my own index viewer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Awesome native way to display the index of a selected vertex, as seen in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TlpUGy5aP1Q&t=2m56s):

- turn on *Developper Extras* in **Edit > Preferences > Interface**.
- Then in the **Viewport Overlays**, in edit mode, turn on *indices* (available for meshes, not for curves!)
- Done!

Comment: This works only in Edit mode and displays the vertices before the geonodes modifier is evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

This was very helpful. I would like to suggest adding just two nodes to blinry's setup. If you look at the furthest left point of his outer star you'll notice that should say 10, instead it says 0. Also the furthest right point on the outer star starts at 0.

You want to add a math node after the instance index to make the first index display the number one. This is passed directly to the standalone instance on points node to shift the string value up one place.
and you also need to add another +1 math node inside the node group going into only the tens digit section divide node.

[image]

[image]